# OnClickListner() for Button in ListActivity header is not working

Tags: listview, button, listactivity

In my application, i have a layout which displays bus-stop details in the header of ListActivity while displays all available arrival predictions as a list. List header contains two buttons, first for saving bus-stop to database and second for refreshing the activity. But  OnClickListner() is not working. I have tested my code without onClickListner() and it works fine.
Remember! in my code, buttons are part of fixed list header
I have tried the suggestion already discussed here but those doesn't worked for me. Help me Please...  My code is as follows:

```
public class MainBusStopByIdActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener{

private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
ReadingBusStopByIdData readingData = new ReadingBusStopByIdData();
LinkedList<BusStop> stopList = new LinkedList<BusStop>();
LinkedList<Predictions> predictionsList = new LinkedList<Predictions>();
private AdapterForBusStopById mAdapter;
String userInput;
Button saveButton;
Button refreshButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initialising buttons
    saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
    refreshButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refresh_button);

    // Creating new adapter instance
    mAdapter = new AdapterForBusStopById();

    // Retrieving data (user Input) sent from previous page
    Intent newIntent = getIntent();
    userInput = newIntent.getStringExtra("input");

    // Retrieving data on background thread
    new loadBusStopDetails().execute(userInput);
    new loadBusPredictions().execute(userInput);

    // Setting up onClickListner() for both buttons
    refreshButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.save_button:
        boolean didItWork = true;
        try {
            if (stopList.size() != 0) {
                String stopId = null;
                String stopName = null;
                for (BusStop stop : stopList) {
                    stopId = stop.getStopId();
                    stopName = stop.getStopName().toString();
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainBusStopByIdActivity.this,
                        stopId + "\n" + stopName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                DatabaseAccess entry = new DatabaseAccess(
                        MainBusStopByIdActivity.this);
                entry.open();
                entry.createEntry(stopId, stopName);
                entry.close();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainBusStopByIdActivity.this,
                        "No Bus-stop Information Found!!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            didItWork = false;
            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Error!!!");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();

        } finally {
            if (didItWork) {
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Entry to Favourites");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("Scuccessfully Added Bus-Stop to Favourites...");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }
        }
        break;

    case R.id.refresh_button:

        break;
    }

}



// Adapter Class
private class AdapterForBusStopById extends BaseAdapter {
    private static final int TYPE_PREDICTION = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_BUSSTOP_HEADER = 1;

    private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private TreeSet<Integer> mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();

    public AdapterForBusStopById() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {

        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addSeparatorItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        // save separator position
        mSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_BUSSTOP_HEADER
                : TYPE_PREDICTION;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView
                + " type = " + type);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
            case TYPE_PREDICTION:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.predictions, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.predictionText);
                break;
            case TYPE_BUSSTOP_HEADER:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.bus_stop_header,
                        null);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
}

// Downloading Bus-stop Information
// AsyncTask Class for downloading Bus-Stop data in Background
public class loadBusStopDetails extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, LinkedList<BusStop>> {

    @Override
    protected LinkedList<BusStop> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        stopList = readingData.readStopDetailsByBusStopId(userInput);
        // Retrieving & Showing bus-stop data
        for (BusStop stop : stopList) {
            String stopData = "  NAME:                  "
                    + stop.getStopName().toString() + " ("
                    + stop.getStopPointer().toString()
                    + ")\n  STOP ID:              "
                    + stop.getStopId().toString() + "\n  STOP STATUS:   "
                    + stop.getStopStatus().toString()
                    + "\n  TOWARDS:           "
                    + stop.getTowards().toString();

            Log.d(TAG, "::::::::::::::::::::DATA:::::::::::::::::::\n"
                    + "<<<<<<" + stopData + ">>>>>>\n");
            mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(stopData);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "::::::::::::::::::::DATA:::::::::::::::::::\n"
                + "<<<<<<" + stopList.size() + ">>>>>>\n");
        return stopList;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(LinkedList<BusStop> result) {
        stopList = result;
    }
}

// Downloading Bus-predictions Information
// AsyncTask Class for downloading Bus-Predictions data in Background
public class loadBusPredictions extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, LinkedList<Predictions>> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainBusStopByIdActivity.this);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setMax(100);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected LinkedList<Predictions> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            publishProgress(4);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        dialog.dismiss();

        // Retrieving & Showing bus-prediction data
        predictionsList = readingData
                .readStopPredictionsByBusStopId(userInput);

        for (Predictions prediction : predictionsList) {
            int time = prediction.getTime();
            String stringTime;
            if (time == 0) {
                stringTime = "DUE";
            } else {
                stringTime = String.valueOf(time);
            }
            String predictionData = "       "
                    + prediction.getRoute().toString() + "             "
                    + stringTime + "             "
                    + prediction.getDestination().toString() + " \n ";

            mAdapter.addItem(predictionData);
        }
        return predictionsList;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        dialog.incrementProgressBy(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(LinkedList<Predictions> result) {
        predictionsList = result;
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Displaying related messages if there's something wrong
        if (stopList.size() != 0) {
            if (predictionsList.size() != 0) {
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        MainBusStopByIdActivity.this,
                        "There are no Buses to this Bus Stop in Next 30 Minutes.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    MainBusStopByIdActivity.this,
                    "There is 'NO' Bus Stop Exist with " + userInput
                            + " Bus-Stop ID.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}

}
```

My XML code is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tflImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="2.5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/redtrain128"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textSeparator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>


<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add to Favourites"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/refresh_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Refresh"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:onClick="onClick" />
</LinearLayout>



<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textSeparator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="  ROUTE     TIME        DESTINATION"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:textSize="8pt"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="normal"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have also found following link about this issue but i didn't get how to implement in my case. please have a look, may be you get any idea, link is here:  [for link clik here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414)

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the *android:descendantFocusability* attribute of the parent layout which contains the ListView to value *blocksDescendants* like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"> ...</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**

another approach I take is more convenient imho, supporting complex content and tested on API 10 and higher is:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="YOUR_CLICK_HANDLE"
android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
android:id="@+id/complexButtonLayout"
>
..
complex contents
...
</LinearLayout>
```

You can either use via handle ( your activity hosting the view implements public void YOUR_CLICK_HANDLE(View view); method ) or you register onclick handler programmatically.

however, I use the views in Fragments.

Comment: I have recently updated my code and provided code for doing background tasks as well. it may help you. i have tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. my code works fine if i remove    OnClickListner() from my code but i need it. Any way thanks for your help. Any help in future will be much appreciated.

Comment: actually, it might be not the best appraoch. I'd turn the code "inside out", meaning exteding a default Activity and putting a ListView inside a layout container, rather than extending the ListActivity. Then you'll be doing fine. And if you wish you'll be even able to handle longClicks or simple clicks on the ListView item itself, while keeping the saveButton and refreshButton clicks working. Extending a ListActivity makes only sense if you dont have any other containers on it.

Comment: May be you are right but i am new to android platform. I think it will be very difficult to me to implement what you are saying right now. Reason is that i didn't tried to implement the code in the way you are saying. Anyway i really appreciate your help. Right now i am trying to implement **save** and **refresh** buttons on action bar instead of implementing in list-activity. Thanks

Comment: yeah good idea, it might work with action bar! anyway, it would be very simple to use a ListView internally: you keep your code as is with following changes: 1) you extend the android.app.Activity instead of ListActivity. 2) you put a ListView somewhere in your layout and assign it an id. 3) in the class MainBusStopByIdActivity  you make a class member ListView listView; and initialize it using findViewById() in onCreate() and 4) in your loadBusPredictions.onPostExecute() you set the adapter on that listView member: listView.setListAdapter(mAdapter). thats it!

Comment: Thanks for your help. You was very helpful. You have explain everything in depth. I will try your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Another question; Can you please help me with the following question if you can? Thanks  [Please click here to follow link to my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938476/error-loading-image-from-asset-folder-through-implicit-intent-by-using-phones-i)